# Find order to install dependencies

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, graph

> Given a JavaScript map object of dependencies and their dependencies,
>   determine order to install them:
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> {
>   p1: [p2, p3],
>   p2: [p3],
>   p3: []
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [p3, p2, p1]
> ```

I really feel like there's a dynamic or recursive solution to this that I can't figure out. Is this true? Can it be done better than my approach? Here's my approach with a `while` loop.

```
function installDeps(depsList) {
    var installed = [];
    var order = [];

    while (order.length < Object.keys(depsList).length) {

        for (var depsItem in depsList) {

            if (!installed[depsItem]) {
                var installable = true;

                for (var dep = 0; dep < depsList[depsItem].length; dep++) {
                    if (!installed[depsList[depsItem][dep]]) {
                        installable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (installable) {
                    order.push(depsItem);
                    installed[depsItem] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return order;
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres how I did it properly with topological sorting. Each key of the object is a vertex on a graph, the value dependencies are the adjacent vertices. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddTC4Zovtbc

```
var deps = {
    p1: ['p2', 'p3'],
    p2: [],
    p3: ['p3']
};

function depSort(deps) {
    var visited = [];
    var sorted = [];

    for (var dep in deps) {
        if (!visited[dep]) {
            depSortUtil(dep, visited, sorted);
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}

function depSortUtil(dep, visited, sorted) {
    visited[dep] = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < deps[dep].length; i++) {
        if (!visited[deps[dep][i]]) {
            depSortUtil(deps[dep][i], visited, sorted);
        }
    }
    sorted.push(dep);
}

console.log(depSort(deps));
```